# System of linear equations: condition for uniqueness

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, determinant

Show that the system $$bx + ay =c \\ cx + az = b \\ cy + bz = a $$ has a unique solution if and only if $ abc \neq 0 $. In this case, fix the system.

I gathered the relationships and got $x = y = z = 1/2$, but I couldn't solve the system. Did I miscalculate?

Comment: Does your question have any connection to measure theory or partial differential equations? If not, then why did you select these tags? Also, what does "fix the system" mean?

Comment: FYI you've included a couple tags (measure theory and partial differential equations in particular) that don't relate to the question in an obvious way. Are $a$, $b$, $c$, $x$, $y$, and $z$ assumed to be real numbers?

Answer (score 4):

The hint.

The determinant of this system is equal to $-2abc$

Comment: I've never heard the phrase "determinant of a system" as opposed to the determinant of a matrix; is this usage common?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom What is a problem? Now you heard it! The number of variables is equal to the number of equations.

Comment: not a problem, just a question

Comment: @Omnomnomnom In Russian sometimes say so. (определитель системы может быть даже делителем нуля в кольце коэффициентов) See here: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: Interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to solve the equation

$$\begin{pmatrix}
b & a & 0\\
c & 0 & a\\
0 & c & b
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}c \\ b \\ a\end{pmatrix},$$
which has a unique solution if and only if the matrix is invertible. So calculating its determinant you get $-2abc$, which is nonzero if and only if $abc \neq 0$. This solves the first part of your question. For the second part, invert the matrix and you get the inverse

$$\frac{1}{-2abc}\begin{pmatrix}
-ac & -ab & a^2\\
-bc & b^2 & -ab\\
c^2 & -bc & -ac
\end{pmatrix}.$$

So now you just have to multiply by the vector 
$$\begin{pmatrix}c \\ b \\ a\end{pmatrix}.$$ So the unique solution is

$$\frac{1}{-2abc}\begin{pmatrix}
-ac & -ab & a^2\\
-bc & b^2 & -ab\\
c^2 & -bc & -ac
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}c \\ b \\ a\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{-2abc}\begin{pmatrix} -ac^2-ab^2+a^3 \\ -bc^2 + b^3 - a^2b \\ c^3 - b^2c - a^2c\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: and how do I find the unknowns?

Comment: How do I solve the system?

Comment: That's the solution. You are given variables $a,b$ and $c$ and not numbers.

Comment: Thanks you for help me

Answer (score 2):

This system is equivalent to solving

$$\begin{pmatrix}
b & a & 0\\ 
c & 0 & a\\ 
0 & c & b
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ 
y \\ 
z 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
c \\ 
b \\ 
 a 
\end{pmatrix}$$

The determinant of this matrix is $-2abc$. Thus, the matrix is invertible if and only if $abc\neq 0$. If the matrix is invertible, then a unique solution exists for the system. If not, the system has zero or infinite solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Just solve it.

If $abc\ne 0$ then $a\ne 0; b\ne 0; c\ne 0$

So $bx + ay = c$ means $x = \frac {c-ay}b=\frac cb - \frac aby$.

And $cx + az=b$ means $z = \frac {b-cx}a =\frac ba -\frac cax=\frac ba - \frac ca(\frac cb - \frac aby)=$

$\frac ba - \frac {c^2}{ab}+\frac cby$

And $cy + bz=a$ means $y = \frac {a-bz}c = \frac ac -\frac bc(z)=\frac ac -\frac bc(\frac ba - \frac {c^2}{ab}+\frac cby)=$

$\frac ac - \frac {b^2}{ac} +\frac ca - y$

So we can solve for $y= \frac a{2c} - \frac {b^2}{2ac} +\frac c{2a}$

And plug in $y$ to get $x=\frac cb-\frac ab(\frac a{2c} - \frac {b^2}{2ac} +\frac c{2a})=$

$\frac cb-\frac {a^2}{2bc}+\frac b{2c}-\frac c{2b}=\frac b{2c}-\frac {a^2}{2bc}-\frac c{2b}$

And $z= \frac ba -\frac cax = \frac ba -\frac ca(\frac b{2c}-\frac {a^2}{2bc}-\frac c{2b})=$

$\frac b{2a} +\frac a{2b} +\frac {c^2}{2ab}$

.....

And if $abc = 0$ then one of $a,b$ or $c = 0$

If, say $a=0$ then we have $bx = c$, $cx = b$ and $cy=-bz$.

If $b\ne 0$ then $x = \frac cb$ and we can only have solutions if $c^2=b^2$ and if so than $y=-\frac bc z$ can have infinitely many solutions.

If $b = 0$ then we must also have $c=0$ and $x,y, z$ can be any values.

Similarly sets of infinite solutions occur if $b$ or $c=0$.